# Can a researcher hire 100% themself with funds from H2020 project (or other call)?

Tags: funding, job

Once in some conference I heard that some guy was working as researcher (PI in different projects) at some university in Italy, but he had no official position. I understood that somehow, before entering this university he applied to an H2020 project (no ERC, StG, CoG, or AdV) that he got and that in the conditions he put in the budget 100% of his salary. So he kind of hired himself. Then he was always applying to H2020 (or other) calls in order to get continuity of his contract.

I wonder how this works.

Comment: The answer seems specific to a given university's policies and asking for a list of other universities seems like a shopping question. Both of these questions types are off topic on this site.

Comment: I edited then my question

Comment: Asking about similar situations is also "shopping". Please see this link: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping

Comment: Broadly, your question seems to be abound funding yourself entirely with _soft money_. There are already several questions on that topic on this site: https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=soft+money

Comment: I am closing this question as unclear, because you already described the process and do not specify what you are skeptical about or similar. The answer also seems to have interpreted the question differently than you.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite normal for people to pay 100% of their salary (or the salaries of researchers, post docs, etc) out of H2020 project grants. I'm not following what you see as the problem. It just means that person spends 100% of their time on that research.

Comment: I do not see this as a problem, the other way around! It is because I am thinking about moving to other University, where there are currently no positions offered, but using this mechanism. What I do not know exactly are the details.

Comment: The exact details will be different for every situation. It's unlikely that you can successfully get any H2020 funding without a university affiliation, but if you have a good relationship with where you want to move they may support you for the application, offering the EC assurances that you will be hosted if you get the funding. Or you might have a formal affiliation with no contract with that Uni already. Or, finally, you might apply from your current location and once you have the funding, switch institutions but that only works...

Comment: ...if it is money that comes with you (e.g. an ERC grant) rather than money that is awarded to your institution for you to work on (e.g. most H2020 grant contracts)